# Slick-Slider React controls disappears when moving it, and behind image

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, gatsby

The issue is that the slick-prev button is hidden. I have been trying to set it inside the image using :

```
.slick-prev:before {

  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;

}


.slick-next:before {

  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;

}
.slick-prev { left: 50px }
.slick-next { right: 50px }
```

.slick-next works perfectly, but .slick-prev just disappears when i set that value.

Here's my declaration of the component:

```js
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import React from "react"
import Img from "gatsby-image"
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css"
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css"
import Slider from "react-slick"

function SlickAll() {

  const query = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
    query {
      allFile(
        sort: { fields: name, order: DESC }
        filter: { relativeDirectory: { eq: "main-page-images" } }
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            name
            childImageSharp {
              fluid(maxWidth: 350, maxHeight: 250) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `
  )

  const setting = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    draggable: true,
    arrows: true,
  }


  //Minus 1 for array offset from 0

  return (
    <div>

    <Slider {...setting}>
      {query.allFile.edges.map(image => (
        <div className="imageContainer">
          <Img fluid={image.node.childImageSharp.fluid} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </Slider>
    </div>
  )
}
export default SlickAll
```

image:
As you can see in the images below, when the left value is unset, the control is behind the image. Even if i set left:1px, it does not move, it just disappears.

Anyone know what is going on?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkjoq.jpg

**UPDATE**

The button is behind the image, the default left value is -55, how can i make it show in front of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason left buttons z-index is less than the images. Try to add more z-index to both of them to be shown.

(Or you could make wrapper which shows image as a background and wraps buttons inside of it.)

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: Its not the z-index, i changed it and still no visible changes.

Comment: .slick-next:before {

  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;

}
.slick-prev { 
  z-index:10;
  left:10px;
 }
.slick-next { 
  right: 20px 
  
}